# Accepting values from dynamically created form elements with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

If this question exists elsewhere on SO please enlighten me, was not having any luck in my searches.

The Dilemma:

I'm building an interface that will enable my wife to upload/manage the photos on her site.
To streamline the process - i built a component to duplicate the 'add a photo' form row wherein she would be able to add multiple images at once Like so:

The mark up: (generated by Zend_Form)

```
<section id="add-photos">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/photo/add-photos" method="post">
        <dl class="zend_form">
            <dt id="AddPhotos-label">&#160;</dt>
                <dd id="AddPhotos-element">
                    <fieldset id="fieldset-AddPhotos">
                       <dl> <-- This element is what get's duplicated on the 'add 
                                another image' button -->
                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id" />
                         <dt id="image_name-label">
                             <label for="image_name" class="required">Image Name</label>
                         </dt>   
                         <dd id="image_name-element">
                             <input type="text" name="image_name" id="image_name"    
                                 value="" />
                         </dd>
                         <dt id="album_name-label">
                             <label for="album_name" class="required">Album Name</label> 
                         </dt>
                         <dd id="album_name-element">
                              <input type="text" name="album_name" id="album_name" 
                                  value="" />
                         </dd>
                         <dt id="category_name-label">
                              <label for="category_name" class="required">Category 
                                   Name</label>
                         </dt>
                         <dd id="category_name-element">
                               <input type="text" name="category_name"  
                                       id="category_name" value="" />
                         </dd>
                         <dt id="image-label">
                               <label for="image" class="optional">Image:</label>
                         </dt>
                         <dd>
                             <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="134217728" 
                                  id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" />
                             <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
                         </dd>
                         <dt id="thumbnail-label">
                             <label for="thumbnail" class="optional">Is Thumbnail?
                             </label>       
                         </dt>
                         <dd id="thumbnail-element">
                             <input type="hidden" name="thumbnail" value="0" />
                             <input type="checkbox" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" 
                                 value="1" />
                         </dd>
                         <dt id="AddAnotherPhoto-label">&#160;</dt>
                         <dd id="AddAnotherPhoto-element">
                             <button name="AddAnotherPhoto" id="AddAnotherPhoto"  
                                 type="button">Add Another Photo</button>
                         </dd>
                     </dl>
                 </fieldset>
             </dd>
            <dt id="submit-label">&#160;</dt>
                <dd id="submit-element">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </form>     
</section>
```

If the user were to click on the 'AddAnotherPhoto' button, it would add another `<dl>` inside the `<fieldset>`. So the structure would become:

```
<fieldset>
    <dl></dl>
    <dl></dl>
</fieldset>
```

But, as you would expect with my controller action:

```
public function addPhotosAction()
{
    $form = new Form_AddPhoto();
    if($this->_request->isPost()){
        if($form->isValid($_POST)){
            $photo_model = new Admin_Model_Photo();

            $photo_model->addPhoto(
                $form->getValue('image_name'),
                $form->getValue('album_name'),
                $form->getValue('category_name'),
                $form->getValue('thumbnail')
            );
        }
    }
    $form->setAction('/admin/photo/add-photos');
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

It's only capturing one set of elements. So my questions is: how do I capture all incoming elements in a grouped fashion? Is there a way iterate through the request object and call the addPhoto method in the Photo Model for each set?

I tried doing this in on the front-end through an `$.ajax()` where the iteration was easily executed, however the data was not so easy to pass to the action.

Let me know if there are better ways architecturally to solve this - or perhaps other examples where this is being done.

Thanks,
Ken

I had a hard time explaining this so let me know if you need something clarified.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632296/zend-framework-add-new-input-element-using-javascript/5640268#5640268

Comment: can you see the whole data set with `$form->getValues()`, it should return an array with all the values posted and filter/validated. You may just have to iterate the array to get all the photos.

Answer (score 1):

If i where u i would create a subform for each addphoto part.
then if u copy it make sure u change the id which it will be grouped with.

With this subform u can then use the following function

```
$form->setElementsBelongTo(<uniqid>);
```

This makes it group the elements in the uniqid so u will get all post results.

So your element will have a name that looks like name="test[image_name]"

In your controller u can then user $form->getValues() to get all values of your form then loop that data with a foreach loop